# i want to redirect the tabs that are currently used by a customer after x minutes of inactivity

Tags: javascript, php

i want to redirect the tabs that are currently used by a customer after x minutes of inactivity 
i have checked the browser activity and is displaying well ie checking if browser is active or not for 30 sec if it is not active i want to redirect to a default page. Now the code shows

> Error in invocation of tabs.update(optional integer tabId, object updateProperties, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'tabId': Value must be at least 0.

i have added permission in my manifest.json file

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "geolocation",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "idle",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "browsingData",
    "cookies",
    "contextMenus",
    "webRequest",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
chrome.idle.queryState(30, function(state) {
    if (state === "active") {
        console.log('Computer not locked, user active in the last 5  minutes');
    } else {
        console.log('sorry Computer  locked, user nop active in the last 5 minutes');

        chrome.storage.local.get("appsLog", function(obj) {
        theAppsLog = obj.appsLog;
        $.each(theAppsLog, function(index, element) {
            theAppsString = element.app;
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                console.log('sorry hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh');
                chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
                    active: true,
                    url: chrome.extension.getURL('html/onionid-ban-inactive-app.html')
                });

            });
        });
    }
        });
```

Comment: Show the relevant code not the manifest.json.

Comment: sorry i missed that

Comment: You know that the method `getSelected()` is deprecated since vhrome version 33?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in my comment above, the method `getSelected()` is deprecated since Chrome version 33.

Instead of this method you can use `chrome.tabs.query()`.

Example (not tested):

```js
// Define the properties
var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
};

chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    // Getting the tab
    var tab = tabs[0];

    // Your code here ...
});
```

More info about this method you can get here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.
But it shows " Unchecked runtime.lastError: No current window" .
i want to redirect the tab to another default page   using chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {

Comment: Try without `currentWindow: true`

Comment: yes i tried that and working now i have a related issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838971/all-the-opened-browser-window-should-be-redirect-to-a-default-page-after-inacivi
please help

Comment: Hi i need to update the tab that is both active and inactive . Then what value can assign to var queryInfo = {
    active: ,

Comment: Just pass an empty object: `queryInfo = {}`