# All the opened browser window should be redirect to a default page after inacivity

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to redirect all the browser tabs when the browser is not active for given time.

In this code I will get the opened applications/tabs url in "theAppsString" then how can i get its tab id and redirect each to a default page.

```js
chrome.idle.queryState(30, function(state) {
  if (state === "active") {
    console.log('Computer not locked, user active ');
  } else {
    console.log('sorry Computer not locked, user nopt active ');
    chrome.storage.local.get("appsLog", function(obj) {
      theAppsLog = obj.appsLog;
      $.each(theAppsLog, function(index, element) {
        theAppsString = element.app;
        var queryInfo = {
          active: false,
          currentWindow: false
        };
        chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
          var tab = tabs[0];
          var tabid = tab['id'];
          chrome.tabs.update(tabid, {
            active: false,
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('html/onionid-ban-inactive-app.html')
          });

        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the tabs.

Example (untested):

```js
chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var tabid = tabs[i]['id'];
        chrome.tabs.update(tabid, {
            active: false,
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('html/onionid-ban-inactive-app.html')
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i tried this this will close all the tabs that are currently in use. but my intention is to get the tab is form the url that i stored in the variable 'theAppsString'..  this variable holds the tab url in a loop can i get the tab id of this url?

Comment: Then check if the tab URL matches the value of your variable.
`if (tabs[i].url == theAppString) { ...`. You need to read the documentation and try byself too, don't expect that you get all your code from other users here on SO ;)

Comment: Hi i need to update the tab that is both active and inactive . Then what value can assign to var queryInfo = { active: